# How to read multiple lines in while statement in ksh

Tags: ksh

I am creating a script to help me through my daily work and automate it. I have encountered my problem when trying to input multiple lines in my while loop. I usually do it in my for loop but I execute it via command.

**Sample:**

```
for i in `cat listoffiles.txt`
do
     echo $i
     find <path> -name *$i* | awk -F "." {'print $4'} #to display a specific value
done
```

Now I am trying to automate it with a while loop. Having problems to read multiple  input lines in it.

For example:

i want to search for these inputs:

For
Example
only

here is my script for it:

```
#!/bin/ksh

echo Please enter file #:
read Var1

while true
do
     VarSession=`find $OT_DIR/archive*/ -name *$Var1* | awk -F "." {'print $4'}`
     if [ "$VarSession" = "" ]
     then
         echo No match for File# $Var1 on this leg or is out of retention.
     else
         echo File# $Var1 is under Session# $VarSession
     fi
done
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Can you not figure out how to make it repeatedly ask you for an input file, or is it not finding the correct information somehow?

Comment: i don't want it to ask repeatedly, i want it to to read the input as a list.

Example:

Please enter File #:

then my input will be

1
2
3
4
5
....

then it will do the command as per line

Comment: @Dan, I tried to read the question, but I can't tell what it is you want to do. The first scriptlet loops over the words in the given files, while the latter just uses the file name as an argument to `find`. So, do you want to read the contents of some file, or just find a file with a given name, or what? Can you add a sample of the input and the expected output, or at least show what the loop variable should contain within the loop?

Comment: So you want the script to go into archive1, archive2 ... archive5 etc and look for files. If files are found then search for specific parameter using `find` and print the output for each file separately?

Comment: @xenodevil yes that is correct, and the command there is correct. what I can't execute properly is finding all the succeeding strings on the archive folder.


Sample Input:

Please Input File#:
Input1
Input2
Input3


Expected output

Input 1 is under session 1234
Input 2 is not found
Input 3 is not found

Comment: and the input that can be put on the script is only 1 line.
how can i put multiple strings with linefeed? when entering the input it runs the script already

Comment: Bash and Ksh are two different shells. I have fixed your question and tag to match your example.

Comment: Why would you use `while`? `for` is doing what you want - run a set of commands for each space separated element - With `while` you have to do the splitting yourself and then traverse through the elements. Btw your while-loop has no exit.

Answer (score 1):

```
VarSession=`find $OT_DIR/archive*/ -name *$Var1* | awk -F "." {'print $4'}`
```

Assuming that you provide `1 2 3` as input, The line above translates to this

```
VarSession=`find $OT_DIR/archive*/ -name "1 2 3" | awk -F "." {'print $4'}`
```

But you want to search all those values separately so you need another loop. `for` loop serves the purpose if traversing white-space separated entries.

Also, based upon the original script that you showed, I assume you want the script to search file by file, rather than scanning entire directories. However, the statement above will put all output in the variable without traversing it. To traverse line by line, `while` loop does the job.

```
#!/bin/ksh

# -n switch suppresses printing a newline
echo -n 'Please enter file #: '
read Var1

# Traverse over all entered values in Var1 (separated by white space)
for i in $Var1
do
        #Set a flag to zero, logic explained later
        Flag=0

        find $OT_DIR/archive*/ -name *$i* | while read FileName
        do
                #Set the Flag to 1 if find command finds something
                Flag=1
                VarSession=`echo $FileName | awk -F "." {'print $4'}`

                if [ "$VarSession" = "" ]
                then
                        #If find found a file but VarSession has nothing then file name is not correct
                        echo "Some conventions went wrong in file name: $FileName"
                else
                        echo "File# $Var1 is under Session# $VarSession"
                fi
        done

        #If find found nothing, there was no match
        if [ $Flag -eq 0 ]
        then
                echo No match for File# $Var1 on this leg or is out of retention.
        fi
done
```

Comment: i'l try this one. this looks i'll get something out of it. thanks